# Gradle Plugin: place a shell script in a Gradle plugin and execute it in runtime when the plugin is applied

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I am developing a Gradle plugin and I want to achieve the following:

- Place a shell script in the plugin artifact (jar).
- Execute the shell script in runtime when the plugin is applied.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance